Finding maximum for a function of $2^b$ non-negative integer variables
Given, $M$ is a positive integer and,$$ 0 \le n_i \le M \hspace{10mm} \forall \hspace{2mm} 1 \le i \le 2^b $$ Then:
$$\max\left\{\sum_{1 \leq i < j \le 2^b} n_i n_j\right\} \hspace{2mm} \text{is} \hspace{2mm}$$
provided  $$\sum_{i=1}^{2^b}n_i = M?$$
For $b = 2$, the solution has been obtained by considering $M$ modulo $4$ and then dealing with all four cases one by one but how should I approach the above question for arbitrary $b$.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Why don't you add the solution you have for $b=2$?

The problem is completely changed with the last modification!

$$
\sum_{1\le i\le j\le n}n_in_j\le\sum_{1\le i, j\le n}n_in_j = M^2
$$
The equality occurs if and only if only one $n_i$ equal to $M$, all other $n_i$ equal to $0$.

@YvesDaoust: Indeed, one way to prove the equality from the term $\sum_{1\le i \le 2^b}n_i^2$ is the following
$$n_i(n_i -M) \le 0 \iff n_i^2 \le M\cdot n_i \qquad \forall 1\le i \le 2^q \tag{1}$$
Take the sum, we deduce that $\sum_{1\le i \le 2^b}n_i^2 \le M^2$
From $(1)$, $n_i$ can only be either $0$ or $M$. We need 1 $n_i$ having the value $M$, the others must all equal to $0$.

The author modified the problem to
$$\max\left\{\sum_{1 \leq i \color{red}{ <} j \le 2^b} n_i n_j\right\}$$
Indeed, the $\le$ is replaced by $<$, which changes completely the problem. So, I provide a new solution for this new problem.
We note that
$$\sum_{1 \leq i  <j \le 2^b} n_i n_j = \frac{1}{2} \left(M^2 -\sum_{i=1}^{2^b}n_i^2 \right)$$
Then, we need to minimize (and not maximize as in the initial problem) the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{2^b}n_i^2 $ with the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{2^b}n_i =M$.
We observe that, to reach the minimum, the difference between any $n_i$ and $n_j$ cannot be greater than $1$. Suppose to the contrary that $n_i – n_j \ge 2$, then it is possible to make the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{2^b}n_i^2 $ lower by replacing $(n_i,n_j)$ with $(n_i-1,n_j+1)$ (the total sum does not change with this transformation) because
$$(n_i-1)^{2^b} + (n_j+1)^2 = (n_i^2 + n_j^2 ) -2 \underbrace{(n_i-n_j-1)}_{\ge 1} <  n_i^2 + n_j^2 $$
Therefore, the minimum is reach when there is $k$ variables receiving the value $v+1$ and $(2^b -k)$ variables receiving the value $v$. $k$ and $v$ can be determine from:
$$\begin{align}
\cases{k\cdot (v+1) + (2^b-k)v = M \\ 0\le k < 2^b} 
&\iff \cases{k + 2^b v = M \\ \\ 0\le k < 2^b } \\
&\iff \color{red}{\cases{v = \left[  \frac{M}{2^b} \right] \\ k 
=M - 2^b v= M - 2^b \cdot  \left[  \frac{M}{2^b} \right]  }}\tag{1}
\end{align}$$
Where $[ x ]$ is  the floor function of $x$.
And the minimum is
$$\color{red}{\max \left\{  \sum_{1 \leq i  <j \le 2^b} n_i n_j \right\}  =\frac{1}{2}\left(M^2 - k(v+1)^2 - (2^b-k)\cdot v^2\right)}$$
where $(k,v)$ are defined by $(1)$.
